# How to perform Partial Reload with Left Join on Qlik?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a Qlik script where I load two tables, `Product` and `Customer`. I join these two tables on a common field called `Purchase_ID` using a left join. **I want to do a partial reload on the `Customer` table using the Partial Reload button to see the updates when new customers are added to the `Customer` table.** However, this does not update my sheet when the Partial Reload option is selected as shown below:
[image]

I tried using the `ADD ONLY LOAD` option but this requires me to click the Reload button each time I load the dashboard, else I get an `Incomplete Visualization` error as it loads the `Customer` table only when a Partial Reload is initiated. I also tried using an `if PartialReload = 0 then ... endif` condition for the Product table but I get a `No Table to Join` error.

How can I do a Partial Reload in this situation? Here is my script for reference:

```
LOAD 
    Product_ID, 
    Cost_Per_Unit, 
    Purchase_ID,
    Date
FROM Product
WHERE Date > '2023-06-01'

LEFT JOIN

ADD LOAD 
    Customer_ID, 
    Purchase_ID
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `If ... Then` needs to be tweaked, as you should be using the [`IsPartialReload()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/SystemFunctions/IsPartialReload.htm) to achieve this:

```
LOAD 
    Product_ID, 
    Cost_Per_Unit, 
    Purchase_ID,
    Date
FROM Product
WHERE Date > '2023-06-01';

If Not IsPartialReload() Then
    LEFT JOIN
    LOAD 
        Customer_ID, 
        Purchase_ID
    FROM Customer;
End If
```

### Edit

After taking into account your comments and re-reading your original question, I'm now understanding your issue much more. I have spun up a database with the same two tables from your example (Customer and Product) and with the same fields to try and replicate the issue.

One possibility for why the partial reload is not working is that it actually *is* working but your use of the `Left Join` is not actually what you want. Based on your example script, you are wanting to fully load both the Customer and Product tables while only partially reloading the Customer table. The problem I found when testing this out was that the `Left Join` is only going to load any new Customer records if the `[Purchase_ID]` field is already in the Product table from the original, "normal" reload. If, when trying to load new records from the Customer table using a partial reload, you are also pulling in new `[Purchase_ID]`s, then there won't be values to successfully `Left Join` to the Product table on.

You can test this theory by simply removing the `Left Join` from your original script. Everything worked correctly for me when I did this by adding new customer records and then doing a partial reload.

[image: Screen recording GIF of Qlik Sense partial reload button]

### Edit 2

The solution posted in [this Qlik Community thread](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Left-Join-in-Partial-Reload/m-p/671220/highlight/true#M668891) allowed me to use a `Left Join` in both the regular and partial reload scenarios. This is the script I used:

```
IF IsPartialReload() THEN
     DROP TABLE [Product];
END IF;

[Product]:
ADD SELECT
    "Product_ID",
    "Cost_Per_Unit",
    "Purchase_ID",
    "Date"
FROM "public"."Product"
  WHERE "Date" > 'Jan-08-2022';
;

LEFT JOIN ([Product])
ADD SELECT
    "Customer_ID",
    "Purchase_ID",
    "Customer_Name"
FROM "public"."Customer";
```

The `DROP TABLE [Product]` is what appears to get this working, along with using the `ADD` prefix on *both* tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not understand where the Customer table would come from - as I do a left join I have only one table, no resident tables. `Customer` and `Product` are names of the tables in the database I am loading the data from.

Comment: The concept is the same, I just used `Resident` because I copy-pasted some script that I'd written for one of my own apps. I just edited my script example to match how you wrote your Load statements

Comment: This does not account for the case when I want to do a Partial reload..do I add an additional if condition for the `If IsPartialReload()` condition?

Comment: Gotcha, I just reread your question a few more times and have added a new **Edit** to my answer above

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However since I do a left join, I already load all my data in the Product table so all the possible `Purchase ID's` are already present. My question is, in your script without the use of `ADD` or `REPLACE`, how would the partial reload button know which table to partially reload? If I understand correctly, the current script is no different than a normal load.

Comment: See **Edit 2** above

Comment: When you use `ADD` for both tables, it will no longer be a partial reload. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The key is that `ADD` works for both regular **and** partial reloads. It would be only used in partial reloads if you used `ADD ONLY`. Check out the table at the bottom of [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Add.htm)

Comment: Also I think I see what you're saying, if you drop the table and then recreate it during the partial reload, then it isn't much of a partial reload. I'm not sure there's any "pure" way around that currently possible. You *may* be able to get clever by using [`Left Keep`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Keep.htm) during the regular reload so that you get the benefits of a left join without actually combining the tables. Then, you could presumably `Add` the Customer table during the partial reload thus avoiding dropping Product

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed it looks like a partial reload in a left join is currently not possible.